# Create custom Gnome Audio Profile

Tags: sound, ogg-opus

I like to convert my music and podcasts to .opus. I would like to be using gnome audio converter, but it only allows very crude settings. So until now I've been converting my files using opusenc in the terminal, where I can specify all the options I want. However, this is very cumbersome as it doesn't convert files in parallel and when the source is in mp3, you already have to create some pipeline.

On the notes to this feature request for gnome audio converter (https://blueprints.launchpad.net/soundconverter/+spec/low-bitrates-for-speech-opus) I read that one could create a custom Gnome Audio Profile. This seems to be exactly the thing I am looking for. However, all the relevant documentation is really old, so I am not sure how I can actually do this.
This (https://www.unix.com/man-page/sunos/1/gnome-audio-profiles-properties/) specifies some commands, and the packages listed here (https://command-not-found.com/gnome-audio-profiles-properties) also don't seem to exist anymore.

Are Gnome Audio Profiles outdated or can I actually manually create a g-streamer pipeline that I can use via gnome-audio-converter?